# ¿Se puede lanzar una excepción cuando a un procedimiento no se le pasa un número de parámetros "x"?

Tags: mysql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Buenos días (o tardes/noches :p) a todos, os expongo el problema:

Yo creo un procedimiento al que por parámetro se le pasa un número de departamento, es decir, un solo parámetro, y al ejecutar, si no le paso ninguno (o le paso 2 en vez de 1 solo), salta un mensaje de error. Mi intención es que cuando pase esto, es vez de saltar el error, salte una excepción mía (lanzada con raise mi_excepción), que diga "no has introducido "x" parámetros", pero no sé cómo hacerlo, no sé ni tan siquiera si se puede hacer, porque lo he estado investigando y no he sacado nada en claro.

```
El mensaje de error al ejecutar el procedimiento sin parámetros es el siguiente:
Error que empieza en la línea 69 del comando:
execute borrar_dep()
Informe de error:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'BORRAR_DEP'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Un saludo a todos y muchísimas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las excepciones del tipo `PLS` son excepciones lanzadas por el compilador de PL/SQL y no pueden ser manejadas dentro del tiempo de ejecución como las excepciones de tipo `ORA`, las cuales son en realidad encapsulamientos de las primeras.

Te invito a consultar [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23559117/11188365) respuesta dada a la misma problemática en SO.

Comment: Eres libre de traducir dicha respuesta y solo dejar la atribución al autor original, de ese modo tu respuesta se enriquece